# iOS how to determine if the screen has been tapped

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I am using iOS 5.x SDK and I want to determine if the screen has been tapped

For now just putting up an NSLog is fine but I don't know where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally with [gesture recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer), e.g.,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnView:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

You then have a method like:

```
- (void)tapOnView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Tap at %1.0f, %1.0f", location.x, location.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with implementing `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`.

You can read more about it here: [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a)